# Readonly cross-class references: A Catch-22

Tags: c#, hierarchical-data, readonly

We have a set of classes that exclusively use `readonly` fields to help ensure that the classes are safe and stable across the scope of the software, especially across threads.  Read-only data, as we all know, is a Good Thing™.

In particular, these classes use `readonly` to ensure that other developers working in the codebase cannot alter them — even by accident — including within methods in the same class:  It's a safety check to keep coders of lesser skill or of lesser codebase knowledge out of trouble, which is why these classes prefer to use `readonly` rather than just to have a property with a `private set` method.  There is no better safety check than the compiler itself telling you "*NO*".

---

But there's an interesting Catch-22 that shows up when *everything* is `readonly`, which is that parent/child relationships become impossible if the references are supposed to point *both* ways.  Consider the code below:

```
public class Parent
{
    public readonly IList<Child> Children;

    public Parent(IEnumerable<Children> children)
    {
        Children = Array.AsReadOnly(children.ToArray());
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public readonly Parent Parent;

    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

This is legal C# code.  It will compile.  And it's the right way to model the relationship.

But it's impossible to instantiate either `Parent` or `Child` correctly:  `Parent` cannot be instantiated until you have a full collection of children to attach to it, but each `Child` cannot be instantiated without a valid `Parent` to hang it off of.

(In our case, the data forms trees, but this problem shows up in many other scenarios:  Variations on this same problem show up in `readonly` doubly-linked lists, `readonly` DAGs, `readonly` graphs, and so on.)

---

Typically, I've worked around this Catch-22 using some kind of hack.  Options I've used in the past include:

- **Remove `readonly` from `Child.Parent`, and use a comment to tell people not to write to that field.**  This works, but it relies on human trust, rather than on the hammer of the compiler telling people not to do something they shouldn't.
- **Make `Child.Parent` into a property with an `internal set`.**  This works, but allows other methods in the same assembly to potentially change `Child.Parent` as well, which violates the design goal of having everything be `readonly`.
- **Make `Child.Parent` into a property with a `private set`, and add an `internal Child.SetParent()` method.**  This works, but it allows methods on `Child` to potentially change `Parent` directly, and still provides a loophole for code elsewhere in the same assembly to alter `Child.Parent`.  And while the `Parent()` constructor remains O(n), its constant-time performance is substantially worse.
- **Make the `Parent()` constructor clone each `Child` instance using a `Child.Clone()` method.** This works, but it violates the expectation that the instances you pass in are the instances that `Parent` will store.  It also can make the `Parent()` constructor run in potentially much worse than the expected O(n) time if the clone is a deep clone, which violates expectations for the construction performance of `Parent`.
- **Make the `Parent()` constructor take the actual `IList`, instead of taking an `IEnumerable` and creating a `readonly` duplicate.**  This works, but it trusts that the caller will not use the list after `Parent` has been constructed.  It also changes the expected behavior of the `Parent()` constructor that you can pass in a collection of any type and it will "just work."
- **Make the `Parent()` constructor use reflection to update `Child.Parent`.**  This works, but it's sneaky and "magical", it violates the expectation that `Child.Parent` won't change after `Child` is constructed, and it's a lot slower than direct writes to the fields.

In short, there's not an easy answer for this problem that I've been able to find.  I've used each of the above solutions at various points in the past, but they're all sufficiently distasteful that I'm wondering if anyone has a better answer.

---

**So, in summary:  Is there a better solution that you've found to the Catch-22 of having exclusively `readonly` cross-class references?**

---

*(And yes, I know that in some ways, I'm trying to use technology to solve a people problem, but that's not really the point:  The question is whether the cross-class `readonly` pattern can be made functional, not whether it should exist in the first place.)*

Comment: For the record, if this was C++, I'd use the `friend` keyword to solve this. But this is C#, and `friend` isn't a thing >_>

Comment: Terminology nit-pick. You should be using the word `immutable` not just `readonly`. You can have a readonly field but the properties inside the field can change internally.

Comment: That's a fair nit-pick, but given that all the classes involved have nothing but `readonly` fields themselves, I think it's fair to call the whole pile of it read-only.  But yes, this is fundamentally a question about the inability of immutable data structures to be recursive, and how to resolve that problem given the tools available in C#.

Comment: Can you not pass the Parent constructor a `Func<TParent, IEnumerable<TChild>>`. The parent constructor can then construct its children (much like real life!), by calling the func and passing `this` as the parameter. The child constructors can store the parent to their read only field, and the parent can do the same with the result of the func. No compromises required.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion, of using delegation to construct the children "inside" the parent's constructor.  It inverts control and forces the children to be constructed at a specific time, but you're right that it _does_ actually work to ensure that all parties have access to all the pointers when they need them.  You should write a longer version of this solution as a proper Answer so it can get some upvotes :-)

Comment: @Iridium, if in constructor you passing `this` to another object, you need to be sure that another object will do nothing with "this" or at least you put this line at the bottom of constructor. By doing this you will need add some comments to `Child` constructor  that constructor cannot use passed `Parent` because it possible that not all `Parent`'s properties initialized yet. Or you put comments in `Parent` constructor that "this line must be always last". So my point: by trying to eliminate one problem by some "hacky" workaround you will create, as usually in such cases, another.

Comment: I have added my commented suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, another possibility which does not require compromising the readonly-ness of your parent/children references is to construct your "Child" objects by way of a factory method passed into the "Parent" object:

```
public class Parent
{
    private readonly Child[] _children;

    public Parent(Func<Parent, IEnumerable<Child>> childFactory)
    {
        _children = childFactory(this).ToArray();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    private readonly Parent _parent;

    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }
}
```

There are many ways to generate the factory passed to the `Parent` constructor, e.g. to just create a parent with 5 children you might use something like:

```
private IEnumerable<Child> CreateChildren(Parent parent)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        yield return new Child(parent);
    }
}

...

var parent = new Parent(CreateChildren);

...
```

As was also mentioned in the comments, this mechanism is not without its potential downsides - you must ensure that your parent object is fully initialized before calling the child factory in the constructor, since it may perform actions (call methods, access properties, etc.) on the parent object, and so the parent object must be in a state where this will not result in unexpected behavior. Things become more complicated if someone derives from your parent object since the derived class will never be fully initialised before the child factory is called (since the constructor in the base class is called before the constructor in the derived class).

Your mileage may therefore vary, and it's up to you to determine whether the benefits of this approach outweigh the costs.

Comment: To be sure, this can get messy with inheritance or delayed constructions, and it has some definite caveats with initialization order and inheritance — but it is still an actual _working_ solution that does not require compromising the `readonly` integrity, and for that fact, it definitely gets my upvote.  I've been experimenting with this pattern in one of our codebases, and I've found it often reads nicest if you do the construction of the children inside a multi-line lambda inside the parent:  `parent = new Parent(p => { ...make children... });`

Answer (score 1):

What you are really talking about are immutable classes, not just read-only fields. So to solve your problem take a look at what [Microsoft's immutable collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable(v=vs.111).aspx) do.

What they do is they have "[builder classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn638265(v=vs.111).aspx)" which are the only things allowed to break the rules of immutability, it is allowed to do it because the changes it makes are not visible external to the classes till you call `ToImmutable()` on it.

You could do similar with a `Parent.Builder` that could have a `public void AddChild(Foo foo, Bar bar, Baz baz)` which adds a child to the internal state of the parent.

Once everything is added you call `public Parent ToImmutalbe()` on the builder and it returns a `Parent` object that has all of it's immutable children built up.

Comment: That still presents a problem of how `AddChild()` and `ToImmutable()` are implemented internally. `AddChild()` presumably can't create an actual `Child` instance, since there's no `Parent` yet to attach it to. So `ToImmutable()` must be responsible for creating the real `Child` instances from `PartialChild`, but it needs a `Parent` to attach them to, and one doesn't exist yet because it can't until all the `Child` instances are created.  Having a `Builder` class is an interesting idea, but really just moves the problem, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more design problem than language.

Does `Child` class really need to know about `Parent`?
If so, then what kind of information or functionality it needs. Can it be moved to the `Parent`?
If you follow "Tell not ask" rule/principle, then in `Parent` class you can call  `Child` methods and pass `Parent`'s information as parameters.

If you still stay will current approach then as your `Parent` and `Child` classes have "circular" dependency which can be resolved by introducing new class which combine them both.

```
public class Family
{
    private readonly Parent _parent;
    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Child> _childs;

    public Family(Parent parent, IEnumerable<Child> childs)
    {
        _parent = parent;
        _childs = new ReadOnlyCollection<Child>(childs.ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  The methods that exist on `Child` belong on `Child`, and the methods that exist on `Parent` belong on `Parent`.  And both the `Children` and `Parent` pointers are necessary — the circular dependency is necessary — because some code needs to walk up the tree, and some other code needs to walk down it.  Some code needs to zigzag and go both ways.  And having a `Family` wrapper isn't viable if the hierarchy goes deep across many types, or the data structure is something like a graph.  This really is a language problem, not a design problem.

Comment: @SeanWerkema, does it `Child` responsibility to know about hierarchy. I think it is not - it need to be responsibility of the class which goes through hierarchy. And this class need to know about all parents and childs involved in the hierarchy.

Comment: You're thinking too much about a specific imagined code problem, and not enough about the general class of problems: Immutable data structures fundamentally *cannot* be recursive. It doesn't matter if they're trees with back pointers, or circularly-linked lists, or DAGs with back pointer sets, or arbitrary graphs; the basic problem remains the same. So if you actually *need* a recursive immutable data structure, and your language is C#, how do you go about implementing it? That's what the question is really all about.

Comment: @SeanWerkema, sorry, it is very possible that I didn't understand fully your problem - for me it is seems like "XY" problem.